# roling object by mose over on left and right side

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I have to make a banner ad (swf). So I have a circle object in the middle and i need to start rotating from left to right when you move the mouse on the right side and to start rotating from right to left when you move the mouse on the left side. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, but try this first and see if its what you're looking for:

```
private var rotationStep = .25;
private var newX:int;
private var oldX:int;

public Main():void {

   // Initialization of your stuff 

   // When ready add this to track the mouse
   this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,followMouse);

}
private function followMouse(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(this.newX > this.oldX) {
        this.rotate(1);
    } else {
        this.rotate(-1);
    }
    this.oldX = this.newX;
}

private function rotate(dir:int):void {
    // rotate ball based on direction
    this.ball.rotoationZ += this.rotationStep*dir;
}
```

Remember rotation is in Radians, not degrees